# What is causing self to be undefined in my AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, lldb

I've been working on an app for a few weeks, then did a major refactor and somehow have broken my app delegate.

If I put a breakpoint in `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, and type `p self` I see the following error:

```
error: <EXPR>:1:1: error: use of unresolved identifier 'self'
self
^
```

If I put a breakpoint in `applicationDidBecomeActive` and type `p self` then I don't get any errors and self appears to be "defined" correctly.

**If I start with a fresh project I don't have this problem.**

My `AppDelegate.swift` is as follows:

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

         return true
    }

}
```

Comment: After much googling it appears to be an lldb bug, because `frame variable -L self` shows the contents of self successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried it in Xcode 7 and I can `p self` successfully.

Then I switched back to Xcode 6 and `p self` is working again.

Pretty much confirms it's a bug and the workaround is to run your project in Xcode 7, without updating your syntax (I had to temporarily comment out some code that wouldn't compile in Xcode 7), then switch back to Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1):

"self" is trickier for the expression evaluator than you might naively think.  It can't just tell the compiler about the variable, it has to convince the compiler that the code in the expression is running in a method context for whatever class "self" happens to be, and then the compiler will infer the presence of self.  Otherwise things like bare ivar access and method invocation wouldn't work.

There were initially a bunch of problems with this little two-step, but these should have been sorted by Xcode 7.  If you are seeing this problem in Xcode 7, please file bugs and we'll take a look.